# gsl::span<T> and gsl::span<const T> overloads are ambigous

Tags: c++, c++14, cpp-core-guidelines

[C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) promotes the practice of [using `span`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-range).

The problem is with const and mutable ranges. This is what I tried to do:

```
auto foo(gsl::span<int>);         // 1st
auto foo(gsl::span<const int>);   // 2nd
```

But they can't be called without explicit `span` cast/construct of the argument:

```
std::vector<int> v;
const std::vector<int> cv;
const std::vector<int>& crv = v;

// ambiguous
// want to call 1st
foo(v);

// ambiguous, although 1st is illegal (static_assert kicks in)
// want to call 2nd
foo(cv); // ambiguous
foo(crv); // ambiguous
```

What is the proper way to deal with this?

**This seems like something that should be trivial, analog to `const T&` and `T&` overloads, yet it isn't** (or I just don't see it).

Just to be on the same page, `foo(gsl::span<int>{v})` is cumbersome, and I want to avoid it, leave the callers simple: `foo(v)`.

---

I generalized the issue, but just in case this is an XY problem, this is what I actually try to do:

```
auto split(gsl::cstring_span<> str) -> std::vector<gsl::cstring_span<>>;
auto split(gsl::string_span<> str) -> std::vector<gsl::string_span<>>;
```

and want to be callable with `[const] char *`, `[const] string`, etc. arguments.

Comment: `const std::vector< int >`? Sure about that? Shouldn't that be `std::vector< const int >`?

Comment: @DevSolar yes, that's what I meant. think about `const std::vector<int>& crv = v`.

Comment: @DevSolar if you think about `string&` and `const string&` I think it is more clear.

Comment: @DevSolar Nice idea, but not working. Compiler emits _error C2338: The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator<const T> is ill-formed._.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Yes, that too... I was just pointing out that OP's first example (`span<int>`, `span< const int >`) didn't match his second (`std::vector< int >`, `const std::vector< int >`) in intention. (Also, holy necro Batman... :-D )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [P0122R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0122r1.pdf) the relevant constructor of the `span` class is:

```
template <class Container>
constexpr span(Container& cont);
```

So all your 3 examples are unfortunately ill-formed. The second one can be made legal by requiring that this constructor is removed from overload resolution unless <s>`Container::value_type&` is convertible to `span::value_type&`</s> the `Container` is compatible with the span.

Even if we do that, I see no way to allow number 1 and 3, since both overloads require exactly one user-defined implicit conversion.

The usual workaround is to add another level:

```
template<class T>
auto foo( T && x ) { return foo_impl( as_span(std::forward<T>(x) ) ); }

auto foo_impl(gsl::span<int>);         // 1st
auto foo_impl(gsl::span<const int>);   // 2nd
```

Note that `as_span` is not in P0122R1, but it is implemented in the Microsoft GSL. It works because it inspects the type and return a `span<typename Container::value_type>`.

Comment: a small observation: `Container::value_type` is still `int` for (`const vector<int>`). It works because it does `span<decltype(*v.data())>`

Comment: unfortunately there is no `as_string_span`

Comment: @bolov quite sad, I guess you'll have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [sbabbi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35842328/2805305) `as_span` is a decent solution to `span`. However there is no `as_string_span`, which would solve my real problem.

Here is my <del>simple</del> implementation:

```
template <class Char_t, gslx::size_t N>
auto as_basic_string_span(gsl::basic_string_span<Char_t, N> str)
    -> gsl::basic_string_span<Char_t, N>
{
    return str;
}

template <class Char_ptr_t>
auto as_basic_string_span(Char_ptr_t ptr)
    -> std::enable_if_t<
          stdx::is_pointer_v<Char_ptr_t>,
          gsl::basic_string_span<std::remove_pointer_t<Char_ptr_t>>>
{
    Expects(ptr != nullptr);
    return {ptr, gslx::size_cast(stdx::char_traits_length(ptr))};
}

template <class CharT, gslx::size_t N>
auto as_basic_string_span(stdx::c_array_t<CharT, N>& arr)
    -> gsl::basic_string_span<CharT, N - 1>
{
    Expects(N > 0 && arr[N - 1] == '\0');
    return arr;
}

template <class Char_t, class Traits, class Allocator>
auto as_basic_string_span(std::basic_string<Char_t, Traits, Allocator>& str)
    -> gsl::basic_string_span<Char_t>
{
    return {const_cast<Char_t*>(str.data()), gslx::size_cast(str.size())};
}

template <class Char_t, class Traits, class Allocator>
auto as_basic_string_span(
    const std::basic_string<Char_t, Traits, Allocator>& str)
    -> gsl::basic_string_span<const Char_t>
{
    return {str.data(), gslx::size_cast(str.size())};
}

template <class Char_t, class Traits, class Allocator>
auto as_basic_string_span(std::basic_string<Char_t, Traits, Allocator>&& str) =
    delete;
```

Bonus `as_const_basic_string_span`:

```
template <class Char_t, gslx::size_t N>
auto as_const_basic_string_span(gsl::basic_string_span<Char_t, N> str)
    -> gsl::basic_string_span<const Char_t, N>
{
    return str;
}

template <class... Args>
auto as_const_basic_string_span(Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(as_const_basic_string_span(
        as_basic_string_span(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
{
    return as_const_basic_string_span(
        as_basic_string_span(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

And usage:

```
template <class CharT>
auto split(gsl::basic_string_span<CharT> str)
    -> std::vector<gsl::basic_string_span<CharT>>

template <class T>
auto split(T&& str)
{
    return split(as_basic_string_span(std::forward<T>(str)));
}
```